# R cannot load libraries calling lapack functions

Tags: r, linux, gcc, lapack, rcpparmadillo

I'm trying to install some of the popular R packages but somehow my R does not see the lapack installation. Or rather the compiler doesn't see it, I guess, because when it checks LAPACK_LIBS it says it found it. I checked sessionInfo() and La_version() and they both point to where lapack is installed. How do I even go about solving it?

```
> install.packages("RcppArmadillo")
Installing package into ‘/homeUPDATES
/marcin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/RcppArmadillo_0.10.5.0.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1669395 bytes (1.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.6 MB

* installing *source* package ‘RcppArmadillo’ ...
** package ‘RcppArmadillo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++14 accepts -g... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -std=gnu++14 -E
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... (cached) yes
checking whether g++ -std=gnu++14 accepts -g... (cached) yes
checking whether we have a suitable tempdir... /tmp
checking whether R CMD SHLIB can already compile programs using OpenMP... yes
checking LAPACK_LIBS... system LAPACK found
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating inst/include/RcppArmadilloConfigGenerated.h
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/marcin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'   -I../inst/include  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-tbZjLv/r-base-4.1.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/marcin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'   -I../inst/include  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-tbZjLv/r-base-4.1.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/home/marcin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/Rcpp/include'   -I../inst/include  -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-tbZjLv/r-base-4.1.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gsl/lib -lgsl -llapack -lgslcblas -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /home/marcin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-RcppArmadillo/00new/RcppArmadillo/libs
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RcppArmadillo’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/marcin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-RcppArmadillo/00new/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so':
  /home/marcin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-RcppArmadillo/00new/RcppArmadillo/libs/RcppArmadillo.so: undefined symbol: dgesvx_
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/marcin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/RcppArmadillo’
Warning in install.packages("RcppArmadillo") :
  installation of package ‘RcppArmadillo’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmpw0yc9E/downloaded_packages’
>
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I made sure that the blas and lapack .so files have 755 permissions but it didn't help.

**UPDATE 2:**

The same problem occurs when I try to build from source a package that needs lapack. For example, I tried installing the [GpGp](https://github.com/cran/GpGp) package with the following Makevars

```
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS) $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS)
```

and it gives the same problem.

Comment: What does `sessionInfo()` show in the second paragraph?  Which BLAS/LAPACK do you have installed?  Do you also have the corresponding `-dev` packages, easiest via `sudo apt install r-base-dev` ?  There is a fair amount of `/usr/local/opt` in your linker instructions so you may have to consult with local admins.  RcppArmadillo builds and tests fine on all standard systems.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel. I do have the `-dev` packages installed and I installed the newest `r-base` from the `cran40` repo. `sessionInfo()` points to a correct liblapack.so and libblas.so and I even changed their permissions to 755. I am 100% sure the problem is not with RcppArmadillo but on my end. But I'm not sure I understand what you mean regarding `/usr/local/opt`

Comment: Your link line above is `g++ -std=gnu++11 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -L/usr/local/opt/gsl/lib -lgsl -llapack -lgslcblas -o RcppArmadillo.so RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR`  pointing twice to `/usr/local/opt` for GSL (do you use/need it?) and gettext.  Neither comes from RcppArmadillo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So eventually I figured out that the problem was my `~/.R/Makevars` file. Dirk's comment under my original question made me wonder where do these extra commands come from and I found them in `Makevars`. I don't remember when and why I added something to it but when I reverted back to just an empty `Makevars` file everything worked! Thanks Dirk!

Comment: There is always a simple reason hiding all the complex things :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `sudo apt-get update` in terminal. Does it say something is locked? It looks to me like something else is using the depenent files and thus the process is locked. If this is the case you can either wait for the process to be done or reboot.

You can also try to install forcing no lock:

```
install.packages("RcppArmadillo",INSTALL_opts = '--no-lock')
```

You also might also try installing via remotes and the github page which will get you the latest dev version rather than the cran version:

```
library(remotes)
remotes::install_github("RcppCore/RcppArmadillo")
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! So reboot didn't help - in fact i've been trying to fix it for a couple of days now. apt update also works fine. I'm really baffled by this

Comment: Try this, I have a couple other ideas but this first: ```install.packages("RcppArmadillo",INSTALL_opts = '--no-lock')```

Comment: thanks for working with me on it! Unfortunately, it didn't help. Same error.

Comment: LAST RESORT BACKUP FIRST IF WORRIED ABOUT LOSING R FILES: ```sudo rm -rf /home/marcin/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/00LOCK-RcppArmadillo``` then try again with regular ```install.packages("RcppArmadillo")```

Comment: You might also try with ```install.packages("RcppArmadillo",INSTALL_opts = '--no-lock', configure.args='--disable-pkg-config')```

Comment: Thanks Neal. Your second suggestion didn't help, unfortunately. The problem with the first one is that it is only a temporary location, created for and deleted after the installation process. So one install.packages() returns, there is no 00LOCK-RccpArmadillo directory (I checked).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233797/discussion-between-marcin-j-and-neal-barsch).

Answer (score 0):

Please install openblas-dev libraries:

```
sudo apt -y install libopenblas-dev
```

The symbol `dgesvx_` is not found. These are the extern C defines, that wrap to the fortran drivers. Then grepping for the symbol you'll find it here:

```
 ~> grep dgesvx_ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so.3 
    grep: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so.3: binary file matches
```